# VSCode raising error when I try to import an Image in Python

Tags: python-3.x, image, tkinter, visual-studio-code, png

I am using Visual Studio Code Community Edition.

I am using code like below and running it:

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
img = PhotoImage(pathtoimage)
Button(tk, image=img).pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

And when I try to run this, I get this error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "Resources/ytbanner.png": no such file or directory
```

I have quadruple-checked that this exists. I have the script being run in the directory where Resources is and this is happening.
Here's the filetree:

```
Path to my desktop
    Projectname
        Script I'm using
        Resources
            PNG image I want to use
```

Is this some sort of VSCode bug or is it something with the directories?

I'm only 11, so please don't be toxic

Comment: you sure vscode is throwing the error? the editor has nothing to do with the errors that our code throw. it's just python.

Comment: and you can find your current working directory from `import os; print(os.getcwd())` then you can find your way to your file from there

Comment: Try `img = PhotoImage('resource/pathtoimage.png')` ? If it shows error that file does not exists, then it clearly means that the file does not exist in the location specified whatsoever, and this error is not in anyway thrown out by vscode, but its by python. According to your filetree, the image is inside a resource folder, so then you will have to include that also in your path(assuming you're using relative paths).

Comment: I'm sure only VSCode is giving the error. When I run the file in normal Python IDE it works fine.

Comment: @Anupama thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: I think `PhotoImage(pathtoimage)` should be `PhotoImage(file=pathtoimage)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the normal behavior of the VS Code python extension. It automatically `cd` into workspace root. So you have to define the path from the workspace root to the file. while this method works on VS Code, this code will break on other editors because they don't `cwd` into the workspace folder. And also if you open the script from VS Code but this time with an in a different workspace (maybe previous workspace folder's parent or something) it would throw an error. So the solution to this would be something like this:

```
import os
import sys

if sys.argv:
    filepath = sys.argv[0]
    folder, filename = os.path.split(filepath)
    os.chdir(folder) # now your working dir is the parent folder of the script

# and your code
```

If your code didn't run on terminal, if statement will return `False` thus the indented block wouldn't work. However, usually when code isn't running on terminal `cwd` is the parent folder of the file as we want.